# When I have use "on", and "in"?

Tags: questions

My native language is **Spanish**

- When I have that to use "on"?, I read some message like "On my server", "On skype", And more.. But I cannot understand it, why "on"?.

I need know it, thanks!.

Comment: Prepositions can be some of the most difficult bits in a language, any language. In English, *on* usually means what *en* does in Spanish, and sometimes *sobre*.

Comment: Yes I know it, but I don't find difference between "On" and "In", In Spanish you can say "En mi servidor", but in english I don't know is that is "On my server" or "In my server"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no answer to "Why". Prepositions are often one of the most idiosyncratic part of a language.

There are some partial answers (we usually use "on" for a method of transport or medium of communication - on a boat, a train, a TV channel, Skype, Facebook, the Internet) but they are only partial (we use "in" for a car or a newspaper). I'm afraid you just have to learn them - I don't believe there's any other way.